# Check for a Substring in a String with a Switch Statement

Tags: java, string, switch-statement, java-8, substring

I was wondering is to possible to make a `switch statement` which will check if there is ***a substring in the entered string***?

What I mean **is**:

- you enter a string into the console
- the string is modified to all lowercase letters for ease of checking
- a switch statement checks if the string contains a certain substring

Comment: No, you'll have to do it with normal `if` statements.

Comment: Maybe you will find the `String.contains()` method easier to use?

Comment: That would be a contradiction to the fact that `switch` has to select one `case` statement without ambiguity. A string which *matches* one case can’t match a different case, but a string which *contains* one substring can contain another substring without problems…

Answer (score 4, accepted):

While there's no such construct, using Java-8 lambdas you can create something similar if you *really* want. Not that I recommend you to do so, just a proof-of-concept:

```
public class SwitchSubstring {
    private static final SwitchSubstring DONE = new SwitchSubstring(null) {
        @Override
        public SwitchSubstring when(String subString, Runnable r) {
            return this;
        }

        @Override
        public void orElse(Runnable r) {
        }
    };

    private final String str;

    private SwitchSubstring(String str) {
        this.str = str;
    }

    public SwitchSubstring when(String subString, Runnable r) {
        if(str.contains(subString)) {
            r.run();
            return DONE;
        }
        return this;
    }

    public void orElse(Runnable r) {
        r.run();
    }

    public static SwitchSubstring of(String str) {
        return new SwitchSubstring(str);
    }
}
```

Usage example:

```
SwitchSubstring.of("some test string")
    .when("foo", () -> System.out.println("Foo is there!"))
    .when("bar", () -> System.out.println("Bar is there!"))
    .when("test", () -> System.out.println("Test is there!"))
    .orElse(() -> System.out.println("Nothing found"));
```

Prints `"Test is there!"`.

Answer (score 1):

A clean solution exists if you're not afraid to dive into some Java 8 lambda's, combined with javaslang. ([javaslang](http://www.javaslang.io/))
The example posted below, verifies a substring using a javaslang Case predicate:

```
import org.junit.Test;
import java.util.function.Predicate;
import static javaslang.API.*;
public class JavaSlangSwitchCase {

  @Test
  public void javaSlangSwitchCaseWithSubstringAB() throws Exception {
    Match("BlahABBlah").of(
        Case(contains("AB"), o -> run(this::printHasAB)),
        Case(contains("CD"), o -> run(this::printHasCD)),
        Case($(), o -> run(() -> {
          System.out.println("KABOOM!");
        }))
    );
  }

  @Test
  public void javaSlangSwitchCaseWithSubstringCD() throws Exception {
    Match("BlahCDBlah").of(
        Case(contains("AB"), o -> run(this::printHasAB)),
        Case(contains("CD"), o -> run(this::printHasCD)),
        Case($(), o -> run(() -> {
          System.out.println("KABOOM!");
        }))
    );
  }

  private void printHasAB() {
    System.out.println("Has AB");
  }

  private void printHasCD() {
    System.out.println("Has CD");
  }

  public static <T> Predicate<T> contains(T value) {
    return (obj) -> ((String)obj).contains((String) value);
  }
}
```

I use javaslang 2.10-SNAPSHOT. Look at the docs for [javaslang docs](http://www.javaslang.io/javaslang-docs/)
Look for

> 3.6.1. The Basics of Match for Java

Cheers,
Stephan

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean something like this?

```
void findSubstring(String s) {
  String lower = s.toLowerCase();
  switch (lower) {
    case "subStringToFind" : 
      doSomething();
      break;
  }
}
```

or do you want the [ConstantExpression](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-ConstantExpression) to be a `boolean`? That won't work, since you're switching on a `String`.